# In holochain-rust what is the best way get and show a list of all users?

Tags: dht, holochain, holochain-rust

I am wanting to show a list of all users for a particular app in holochain  to enable an active user to make an agreement with someone.   What is a best practice for getting a list of all users given the linking nature of the data flow?

Would it make sense to create a central  agent that links to all the users to get access to the full user list?    Is there a way that seems better?

Answer (score 5):

### Link from the DNA Hash (not recommended; read about anchors below)

Each user could link from the DNA hash to themselves in the `genesis()` function -- the DNA hash is the one hash on the DHT that everyone knows. Then all you need to do is `getLinks(App.DNA.Hash, "user")` to get them all. (watch out, it could get to be a huge list. I also feel bad for the poor nodes who are in the neighborhood of the DNA hash... that's a lot of metadata to store.

### Doing this in Genesis

This can be done in the genesis function. I'll do it in old holochain-proto language, if you don't mind:

```
function genesis() {
    commit({ Links: [ { Base: App.DNA.Hash, Link: App.Key.Hash, Tag: "registered_user" } ] };
}
```

That will create a sort of 'registered agent' thing for each new person who joins.

#### The problem with this approach

it's a bit of an antipattern, because a redundant copy of the DNA lives in the DHT as well, and the poor souls whose nodes are in the DHT hash neighbourhood of the DNA will have a higher load than others. Right now I'd recommend anchors instead. Anchors are nothing but a pattern that consists of a string entry + a link. So you would create an anchor whose content is `"registered_users"`, and link from that anchor to any agent who comes on board. Still creates a hotspot for those who hold the anchor entry, but it's expected that your app will have a few anchors like this, and at least they don't have to all hang off the one DNA hash.

### Linking with Anchors

The [anchors mixin](https://github.com/holochain/mixins/tree/master/anchors) (currently compatible with hc-proto only) features an idempotent function to create the anchor, so each user could safely call `anchor()` without re-creating an existing anchor.